# Mark array of days with a color in pickadate.js calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, pickadate

I want to mark some days with a colour reading the dates from an array that I have to retrieve from the database. I imagine something like the beforeShowDay option in the Jquery UI Datepicker where I can set a class to a certain array of dates.

This is the plugin: http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/

Could you help me figure it out how could I do it?

Thanks